# C++ bool template parameter and compile time if

Tags: c++, if-statement, templates

I have the following function

```
template <bool c>
void func()
{
    ...
    if (c) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

This function is to be used several time inside a loop:

```
for (...) {
    func<true>();
}
```

I would like to know it the if inside func is done compile-time, run-time, or if it is left to the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler may or may not optimize your code since it knows what `c` is at compile time.  The only way to actually know would be to look at the generated assembly code to see if the branch was removed or not. That said, C++17 introduced [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) which is guaranteed to evaluate the condition at compile time and discard the branch that is not taken.  That would make your function look like

```
template <bool c>
void func()
{
    // ...
    if constexpr(c) {
        // do something if c is true, discarded otherwise
    } else {
        // do something if c is false, discarded otherwise
    }
}
```